# js for my slot machine game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just starting to learn HTML, CSS, JS and jQuery and I'm trying to build a simple slot machine site for my own education.

I have three windows each with the same three images cycling through them. When clicked, a window will freeze the current image. What I want to do, is make it so that if the `src` of all three windows is the same after each window is clicked an `alert("You've won")` is called, and if they are not all the same an `alert("You've lost")` is called.

Here's the div:

```
<div class="row forthRow">
    <div class="slotContainer col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
        <img src="image1.jpg" id="mainImage1" class="win_or_lose col-xs-12" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="slotContainer col-xs-4 col-md-2">
        <img src="image2.jpg" id="mainImage2" class="win_or_lose col-xs-12" alt="flame"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slotContainer col-xs-4 col-md-2">
        <img src="image3.jpg" id="mainImage3" class="win_or_lose col-xs-12" alt="bolt"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the .js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter1 = 1;
  var counter2 = 2;
  var counter3 = 3;
  var paused1 = false;
  var paused2 = false;
  var paused3 = false;

  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    delay = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();

    $(".speed_buttons").fadeOut(0, function() {
      $(".start_over_button").fadeIn(0);
    });

    $("p.directionsOtheGame").text("Get three in a row!");

    setInterval(function firstWindow() {

      if (paused1 == false) {
        counter1 = counter1 + 1;
        if (counter1 > 3) {
          counter1 = 1;
        };

        $("#mainImage1").attr("src", "image" + counter1 + ".jpg");
      };
    }, delay);

    setInterval(function secondWindow() {

      if (paused2 == false) {
        counter2 = counter2 + 1;
        if (counter2 > 3) {
          counter2 = 1;
        };

        $("#mainImage2").attr("src", "image" + counter2 + ".jpg");
      };
    }, delay);

    setInterval(function thirdWindow() {

      if (paused3 == false) {
        counter3 = counter3 + 1;
        if (counter3 > 3) {
          counter3 = 1;
        };

        $("#mainImage3").attr("src", "image" + counter3 + ".jpg");
      };
    }, delay);

    $("#mainImage1").click(function() {
      paused1 = true;
    });

    $("#mainImage2").click(function() {
      paused2 = true;
    });

    $("#mainImage3").click(function() {
      paused3 = true;
    });
  });
});
```

I have searched all over StackOverflow as well as W3schools and api.jquery.com to no avail. I hope my problem is clear. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you receiving an error with your current code, or just looking for help with solving the problem? If you just want guidance, that is likely to be off-topic here, because it is probably too broad and would take too much time for anyone to reasonably answer.

Comment: for starters, the code isn't complete, so it might be helpful to someone if you included everything necessary to run the code in the question

Comment: No errors with my current code. I have edited in the complete code. I am looking for a solution to a problem rather than general guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> make it so that if the src of all three windows is the same after each window is clicked

As your images are based on your [global] variables, you don't need to check the `src` you can just check the variables, ie:

```
if (counter1==counter2 && counter1==counter3)
    alert("You've won");
```

this assumes you've already checked that they are all paused:

```
if (paused1 && paused2 && paused3)
  if (counter1==counter2 && counter1==counter3)
    alert("You've won");
```

Comment: Thanks freedomn-m You solution makes perfect sense but when I ad it to my script nothing changes. I know that this is due to my own ignorance rather than your suggestion, yet I do not know what i'm doing wrong. I added your code right under my list of vars saved and refreshed my page and the page and nothing changes. No errors. The page works fine in terms of cycling images and pausing. Just still no alert.

Comment: freedomn-m Thank you! After some tinkering I figured out how to incorporate your answer! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have each window call a function when it is stopped. If all windows aren't stopped, the function does nothing. If they are all stopped, it checks the result.

Also, as a general programming tip, if you do the same thing more than once, make a function to do it. You have virtually identical code duplicated three times, which is bad for several reasons:

1. Any changes (bug fixes, modifications) will have to be duplicated.
2. Your code base is bigger than it could be, making it harder to debug and ship.

Comment: Yes, there's all sorts of code-review type issues with the question code, but reusable functions is probably the best improvement to make.

Comment: Thanks Kittsil. I have edited my question to show the entire .js code. Your tip makes a lot of sense. I am such a rookie with all of this. I've been studying coding for less than a week. I would not know how to start simplifying this down...